# Why won't my for loop quit when the quantity is higher than 1?

Tags: c

I have tried everything to fix it.
Removing this code fixes it but I need it to be there.

```
printf("Would you like a milk with that?\n");
        scanf("%s",&milk);
```

Can someone help me? It is for my school project.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main()
{
    int quantity;
    char milk;
    double price;
    int repeat = 1;
    int choice;
    
    
    printf("Please insert the quantity of beverage you desire\n");
    scanf("%d",&quantity);
    for(repeat = 1; repeat <= quantity;)
    {
        printf("No.  Item           RM\n");   
        printf("1.   Espresso       2.10\n"); 
        printf("2.   Cappuccino     2.20\n");
        printf("3.   Latte          2.30\n");
        printf("Please enter the beverage of your choice (1, 2 or 3)\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);    
        
        printf("Would you like a milk with that?\n");
        scanf("%s",&milk);
        
        ++repeat;
    }
        
    if(choice == 1)
    {
        price += 2.10;
    }
        
    if(choice == 2)
    {
        price += 2.20;
    }
        
    if(choice == 3)
    {
        price += 2.30;
    }
    if(!(choice == 1 || choice == 2 || choice == 3 ))
    {
        printf("Beverage does not exist, please try again later");
        return 0;
    }     
    
    
    printf("The total price is : %f \n",price ); 
}
```

Comment: `%s` is the conversion specifier for a string, but you're trying to read a character. Try `scanf("%c",&milk);` instead. And [read the documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html).

Comment: @r3mainer - Your advice is, excuse me, bad. There's no indication that he is _trying to read a character_. What's more, `scanf("%c",&milk)` would only read the delimiting character of the previous input.

Comment: @Armali OK point taken. I didn't read the rest of the code.

Comment: @r3mainer I tried switching it, now it skipped the milk part straight back to the beverage choice.

Comment: @r3mainer - I have to apologize - there is of course an indication that he is trying to read a character, namely the `char milk;` definition.

Answer (score 1):

- You forgot to initialize `price`.
- You erroneously placed the closing `}` of the `for` loop block before the `if` statements testing `choice`, while it has to go after them, right before the final `printf`.
- To allow for `yes` to be entered as an answer to `Would you like a milk with that?`, you should define `char milk[4];`. To protect against buffer overflow, you should use `scanf("%3s", milk);`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but another thing came out. Now it won't increase the price by 0.50 when milk is Y/y.
I did everything then I added this :
```
 printf("Would you like a milk with that?\n");
        scanf("%3s", &milk);
        
        if(milk == 'Y' || milk == 'y')
        {
            price += 0.50;
        }
```
It wont increase the price when milk is Y/y

Comment: You're reading a string, but comparing it to a char

Comment: You should do `milk[0] == 'Y'` or if you want a string comparison `strcmp(milk, "Y") == 0`

Answer (score 1):

the variable of char milk has only 1 byte space.
but it was used to hold any user input string larger than 1 byte.
so the other variables will be changed after scanf.

```
char milk[256];
```

will solve the stack overflow problem.